# Wordpress 3.1 - Tag page not showing posts from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

On the site I am developing I have a few custom post types set up (Press Releases, Articles, Podcasts). I also have the Tag Cloud widget enabled in my sidebar.

I have tagged a post with 'Testtest', and I've also tagged a Press Release with 'Testtest'. The problem I have is when I click the 'Testtest' tag on my tag cloud, it only shows the 'Post' that I tagged, and not the Press Release.

Any idea why this would be, or a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add them using  pre_get_posts filter:

```
function myTagFilter($query) {
    $post_type = $_GET['type'];
    if (is_tag()){
        if (!$post_type) {
            $post_type = 'any';
        }
        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
    }
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts','myTagFilter');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, where would I put that code?

Comment: Ah nevermind, found where. That does indeed show my other post types, though for some reason my navigation disappears on the tag pages now?

Comment: the only thing this code changes is the post_type query on a tag archive so i can't really tell whats wrong there, if you create a pastebin of your code and output i'll know more.

Comment: I have the same problem - my navigation disappears on the tag pages.I will be very grateful if you find why

Comment: Yeah we are going to need more info like what your tag page code is like

Comment: I am using the default one tags.php .My navigation bar is blog theme->menu. The solution I found is to actually override the wp-query by using **query_posts(array('tag' => $tag,'post_type'=>'any));**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the only fix I've found so far is to wrap the menu with a remove then add of the filter to stop it from breaking the menu.